# How can I rewrite this function in non-recursive form?

Tags: c++, recursion

How can I rewrite this function in non-recursive form?

```
void generate(int pos)
{
  if (pos == n + 1)
  {
    print_table();
  }
  else 
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
      if (!used[i])
      {
        used[i] = true;
        perm[pos] = i;
        generate(pos + 1);////recursion
        used[i] = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does `n` come from?

Comment: What does it matter, @Vite?

Comment: Use an explicit stack?  BTW, what is this function doing?

Comment: The value of 'pos' passed at the initial call to 'generate' is also required

Comment: @RobKennedy: Now that I think of it, not really

Comment: It looks to be using recursion to do a nested-loop ... though the purpose eludes me.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Captain Obvious?

Comment: It generates permutations, I guess.

Comment: n - is global variable

Comment: This function generates the variants of towers positions on chess board

Comment: @user3164957, basically, as far as I can see, it generates permutations of all numbers from 1 to n. It's much easier to find a ready-to-use solution for this task rather than for generating positions of towers on a chess board :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code appears to call `print_table()` for each permutation of the numbers 1,...,n.  There is a built-in tool for this in C++.

```
#include <algorithm>

void generate() {
    int n = 10; // or whatever

    std::vector<int> perm(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) perm[i] = i+1;
    do {
        print_table(perm);
    } while(std::next_permutation(perm, perm+n));
}
```

Comment: Oops: I've fixed it now.  There should be no `used` in this code.

Comment: Thanks! Fine! It almost works. But else, your function generates useless results for me. To my mind this trouble in std:: next_permutation algorithm

Comment: Note that the values are stored in `perm[0], ..., perm[n-1]`, whereas you were perhaps expecting them to be stored in `perm[1], ..., perm[n]`.  It is normal in C/C++ for arrays to be indexed starting from 0.

Comment: Yes, may be, because I start to record units from 1-undex. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be a standard recursive algorithm for generating all permutations of a list of elements. Rather than trying to mechanically massage the recursive algorithm into an iterative one (which would probably require a stack of some sort), you might want to look at iterative algorithms for listing off all permutations of a list. For example, C++ provides the `std::next_permutation` algorithm, which you can use to list permutations. For reference, I have [a simple implementation of this algorithm](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=next-permutation) along with commentary explaining how it works.

Hope this helps!